# how to wait for asynchronous data coming from a subscription

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

So I'm trying to wait subscribe to a data coming from a local storage service, but the data I get from the local storage is sometimes late and the .Uid is not defined

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private cp: CommerceProvider,
            protected localStorage: LocalStorage) {
  this.localStorage.getItem('castra').subscribe((data) => {
    this.uid = data.uid;
    console.log(data);
    this.getCastraProfile();

  })
}

ngOnInit() {
  let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  this.castra_id = id;
  this.localStorage.getItem('cart').subscribe((cart) => {
    if(cart.length == 0){      
      this.localStorage.setItem('castra', { 'uid': this.castra_id 
 }).subscribe(() => {});
    } 
  }, (error)=> {
    this.localStorage.setItem('cart', []).subscribe(() => {});
 });
}
```

so how to wait for this data to come then assign it to the uid variable?

Comment: Is it the web api licalStorage?

Comment: yes it saves to indexDB

Comment: @ngx-pwa/local-storage

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: i want to get the data from the key castra to use it in the template

Comment: but first time the component loads data is undefined

Comment: try by putting it inside `ngOnit`

Answer (score 0):

You can not wait for subscribe method. If you also use wait method than when you load first time your page the subscribe automatically call and you got always null value until your API is not called.

If this you got id is `undefined` than use `if(data)` inside subscribe.

**Example in your case :**

```
this.localStorage.getItem('castra').subscribe((data) => {
   if(data){    
   // This will call if they have some data. It call if data have 'null' or 'Undefined' value.
        this.uid = data.uid;
        console.log(data);
        this.getCastraProfile();
    }
});
```

Comment: okay it's my fault I'm setting the data in the same component let me please edit this

Comment: so I'm setting data in the ngOnInit and getting in the constructor LOL ,,
but still when i put the get method under the set method in the OnInit() it still won't work

Comment: Use only `this.localStorage.setItem('castra', { 'uid': this.castra_id 
 })`; and bind it like this : var localData = this.localStorage.getItem('castra');

Comment: And In your case call `localStorage castra` after view Init. call into `ngAfterViewInit` instead of constructor.

Comment: okay this worked for this component but there's another component calling same data tried to put the get function in     ngAfterViewInit() but that didn't work

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz for that. So i can help you.

Comment: sorry what is a stackblitz

Comment: `stackblitz` is a website, when you can create online angular project for demo purpose or personal study. Refer this link : https://stackblitz.com/